# Limit involving Polygamma function: $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{2x^2}{(x + k)^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, polygamma

I don't remember where I got this identity: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} [(-1)^{k + 1} x^k \psi^{(k)}(x)] = (k - 1)!$$
where $\psi^{(k)}$ is the polygamma function.

I just need to find the limit above for $k = 2$, that is 
\begin{equation}\lim_{x\to \infty} [-x^2 \psi''(x)]. \tag{*}
\end{equation}

I use the series representation of the polygamma function, $$\psi^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^{n + 1} n! \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(x + k)^{n + 1}},$$
and change $(*)$ to

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{2x^2}{(x + k)^3}.$$

I don't know how to proceed further.
Any help would be apreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By L'Hôpital's rule, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\psi^{(k)}(x)}{(-1)^{k+1}x^{-k}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(k-1)!\psi(x)}{\ln x}=(k-1)!.$$

Comment: Wow! I overthink the problem that don't expect such simple solution exists!

Anyway, is there any simple proof for the last limit? I know there is an asymptotic expansion of the digamma function, $$\psi(x) \sim \ln x - \frac{1}{2} - \sum \frac{B_{2n}}{2nx^{2n}}.$$
and the limit follows easily. But is there another way without using this?

Comment: @Azlif Exactly (well, if you change the $z$ to $x$).

Comment: Thanks! that really help me alot